# Make a variable by giving the value of an html DOM

Tags: javascript, html, function, document, getelementbyid

I wanna make a  variable like this:

```
const number = document.getElementById('number');
```

which can be changed as this:

```
number = Math.floor(1 + Math.random() * 20);
```

and I saw that I can select `body` by doing this:

```
const body = document.body;
body.onload = AnyFunction;
```

but I'm also trying to select that id but I don't how to. Big thanks in advance :)

Comment: You want to update value of a specified element?

Comment: First of all, you can't re-assign value of a `const` varibale; So updating value to `number`  will throw error.

Comment: And we need more detail about your purpose, please explain it more clearly.

Comment: I only want a variable that can be changed and will have a value of an HTML DOM id.  I only wanna do something like this:
let variable = document.getElementById('number').innerHTML = Math.floor(
  1 + Math.random() * 20
);
I'm sorry about my bad explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

not really sure what you want to achive.

The first code:
`const number = document.getElementById('number');`
Is getting an HTML Element from the DOM like a DIV or a Paragraph with the ID of Number. Like this:

`<div id="number">...</div>` 
This is not a javascript variable like `const test = 12134;` it is a HTML Object.
You can save content to the element by setting the innerText property like:

```
   const paragraph = document.getElementById("number");
   const number = 12345;
   paragraph.innerText = number;
```

Then you have inserted the numer 12345 into an existing HTML Element with the ID number.

Hope this helps a littel bit.
Sorry if I missed something, is my first question ;-)